# traefik custom service creation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to deploy my own docker container with a http-server inside with traefik via docker-compose. **The example whoami container is recognized via dynamic configuration (so dynamic configuration works in principle)**.
My own container is not recognized when I try to configure it in the docker-compose.yml file. I just change the image in the configuration and nothing else and it doesn't work. The following is just for clarification that I force a port to be used, so lack of exposing a port in the image itself is not the issue.

```
my-service:
 image: my-image
 labels:
  - "traefik.http.services.my-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8002"
```

Are there any properties the image needs to fulfil besides no exiting, to make it able to be recognized by traefik?
When I publish the ports directly in docker-compose.yml I can access the http-server without any problems.

Comment: Please share your Traefik's docker-compose.yml and Traefik's config file (if any). Here's an example I prepared for a demo a couple weeks ago: https://github.com/tribal2/traefik-v2-example

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing labels.

Here's what I would add into a docker-compose, when one of my containers needs to be exposed:

```
labels:
- traefik.enable=true
- traefik.http.routers.myappname.entrypoints=tls
- traefik.http.routers.myappname.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z]+}.subdomain.example.com`)
```

Identifying the application FQDN being the critical part that you're definitely missing - other two would depend on how you configured Traefik.

FYI, the corresponding Traefik container would look like this:

```
traefik:
  command:
[...]
  - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
  - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=tls
  - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
  - --entrypoints.tls.address=:443
  - --entrypoints.tls.http.tls=true
  - --providers.docker=true
  - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
  ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
  volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

Traefik documentation is pretty well done, and would give you a similar sample https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/#details .

As a sidenote, not knowing much about what you would use deploying Traefik, make sure the Docker provider is properly configured: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/

FYI, the `traefik.http.services.my-service.loadbalancer.server.port` label would be used to help Traefik figure out which port should it use, connecting to a backend container.

If that container doesn't have some port exposed, or have several ports exposed -- otherwise, Traefik should be able to find out by itself.

Consider reading the documentation of the proxy you are trying to configure, it's all explained, not a very long read, definitely worth your while.

Comment: My issue is that everything works fine when I use the whoami image that is given in the traefik documentation. Only when I change the image to my own, there is no service and consequently no router created. My idea is that specifying the port with traefik.http.services.my-service.loadbalancer.server.port should force trafik to create a service and router for my custom image, even when it doesn't expose a port. So are there any requirements for the custom image itself?

Comment: no requirements for images. the container should run in a network reachable by Traefik, binding to a non-loopback address. What error are you getting? Can you share docker-compose / URL for that image?